# Using SFINAE to detect method with GCC

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I am having trouble using the SFINAE concept to detect if a class has a particular template method with some compilers, most pertinently GCC.  Consider the code below.  It compiles and works as expected with MSVC; however, when I compile the same code with GCC, it complains that `std::vector<double>` does not have a serialize method.  Of course, the fact that the method does not exist is true, but I expected this to result in a substitution failure and the compiler determining that the other less specialized fallback is most suitable.  Am I missing something about SFINAE or is this a bug with GCC?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

class SerializerBase
{
  public:
    SerializerBase() {}
};

template<typename T>
struct has_serialize
{
    template<typename C>
    static constexpr auto test(...) -> std::false_type;
    /// Note: this is where the compiler complains about the .serialize method
    /// during substitution.
    template<typename C>
    static constexpr auto test(int)
      -> decltype(std::declval<T>().serialize(std::declval<SerializerBase&>()), std::true_type());

    using result_type       = decltype(test<T>(0));
    static const bool value = result_type::value;
};

class Serializer : public SerializerBase
{
  public:
    Serializer() {}

    template<typename T,
             typename std::enable_if<!has_serialize<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
    void operator()(const T& v)
    {
        std::cout << "fallback called" << std::endl;
    }

    template<typename T,
             typename std::enable_if<has_serialize<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
    void operator()(const T& v)
    {
        v.serialize(*this);
    }
};

struct Foo
{
    template<typename SerializerType>
    void serialize(SerializerType& s) const
    {
        std::cout << "serialize called" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Serializer s;
    std::vector<double> v;
    Foo f;
    s(v);
    s(f);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have a typo. `std::declval<T>` -> `std::declval<C>`.

Comment: @n. 'pronouns' m. You are exactly correct.  I misunderstood how substitution works in this case, but as you pointed my error out, I see my folly.  I will try to write up a solution if that would be helpful to others.  Otherwise, I'm fine deleting this question if that is more helpful.  I am new to posting, so any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Writing your own answer that is helpful to others is much preferable to deleting the question IMO.

Comment: I wrote something up.  Any feedback on how to improve the answer or address my lack of understanding regarding this GCC behavior is appreciated.

Comment: I will wait a bit to see if someone else wants to propose a more complete explanation as an answer.  Otherwise, I will accept my own.  Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the event someone else encounters a similar error/misunderstanding, my error (aptly pointed out by n. 'pronouns' m.) was using the wrong type in the `has_serialize::test`.  From what I can infer (in my naivety) is that for

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct has_serialize
{
    // ...
    template<typename C>
    static constexpr auto test(int)
      -> decltype(std::declval<T>().serialize(std::declval<SerializerBase&>()), std::true_type());
    // ...
};
```

the template `C` does not appear in `has_serialize::test`, and as a result GCC does not provide an opportunity for substitution failure.  Consequently, GCC tries to evaluate `std::declval<T>().serialize(...)` and obviously throws an error when `T = std::vector<double>`.  If `T` is replaced with `C` in this line, then the compiler recognizes it as a substitution failure and determines the signature to be unsuitable.

Furthermore, as Maxim Egorushkin pointed out, there is the possibility that `T::serialize` might return a user-defined type that overloads `operator,`.  To ameliorate (albeit very unlikely) potential error, the code should be:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct has_serialize
{
    // ...
    template<typename C>
    static constexpr auto test(int)
      -> decltype(static_cast<void>(std::declval<C>().serialize(std::declval<SerializerBase&>())), std::true_type());
    // ...
};
```

Comment: What is unclear to me is why GCC attempts to evaluate the statement when T is substituted, while it recognizes the substitution failure if C is used (especially since MSVC behaves the same whether T or C is used).

Comment: The result of `serialize` could be a UDT that overloads `operator,` so that it doesn't return `std::true_type`. To handle that, you may like to cast the result of `serialize` to `void` before applying comma operator, e.g. `decltype(static_cast<void>(std::declval<T>().serialize(..)), std::true_type())`.

Comment: You have a great point, I'll edit the answer to include this information.  I know in my code that the return type is never a UDT, but you suggested a good trick to avoid an issue if it were possibly the case.

Comment: MSVC is rather non-standard in its treatment of templates. Until recently it didn't even have two-phase lookup. Not sure about now. Maybe this discrepancy is related to that. Anyway, with `T` in there, there is no substitution (and so no SFINAE) in the return type of `test`, because the template parameter *of `test`* does not appear in it. Template parameters of the surrounding class template are irrelevant.

Comment: @n. 'pronouns' m. Your explanation makes perfect sense on further thought.  My only remaining question is why MSVC works when `T` is used in place of `C`.  I am generally aware that MSVC handles templates quite differently than GCC (and other compilers), but out of my own curiosity, I wish I knew what was happening under the hood (at least in concept).